# AWS Cloudfront - How to dynamically add new domains in aws cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

For one of my customer `customer1.com`, I have used CloudFront as a `reverse proxy` to make the website faster ( and other features through `Lambda Edge` ). 
For this customer, I have added CNAME ( alternate CNAME like customer1.com ) in CloudFront and an ACM certificate. All is good so far.

Now I got a few more customers who want to use my service. If I want to use the same CloudFront distribution for these new customers, I can do that by adding CNAME (like `customer2.com`, `customer3.com` ) in the CloudFront.

Problem is how do I update the `AWS ACM ( SSL Certificate )` to include the domains of the new customers without affecting the website of the old customers

Comment: Different apex domains (example.com, different.org), or subdomains (e.g. customer1.example.com, customer2.example.com)?

Comment: Hi @Marcin : It is different domains like example.com, anotherexample.com,

Comment: 3 and a half years later, did you find a solution for this problem?